# Weird Behavior of Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssis

I've got a trigger (SQL 2008 R2) that does one simple operation but the results are not logical. 
Here is the overview:

A text file is fed to an SSIS package with ONE line(one record) that loads it into "ORDERS_IN_PROCESS" table. The Data Access Mode is set to "Table or view" in the "OLE DB Destination" to allow triggers to fire.

Here is my ORDERS table:

```
OrderID        ItemNo
---------    ---------
9813           1
9813           2
9813           3
9817           1
```

So, SSIS executes and
ORDERS_IN_PROCESS gets one record inserted which is OrderID 9813

Trigger is fired:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OrderID=INSERTED.OrderID
```

Pretty simple so far...

The results I get in my ORDERS_ARCHIVE (identical layout to ORDERS) Table are

```
OrderId       ItemNo
---------   ----------
9813          3
```

Where are the rest of the 2 line items?

Note, it only inserted the last row read from ORDERS table into ORDERS_ARCHIVE.

I need all 3 of them in ORDERS_ARCHIVE.

Why does this happen?

I believe it has something to do with the way SSIS processes it using "OLE DB Destination" because if I insert a record into RLFL manually, the trigger does exactly what it's supposed to do and inserts all 3 records from BACK.

You may argue that trigger fires once per batch and I agree but in this case I have a batch of just ONE record.

I'm thinking of an sp, but i'd rather not add another level of complexity for something so trivial, supposedly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE SELECT * FROM INSERTED`?

Comment: @HABO That's NOT what I need.

Comment: i'm so sorry.  out of curiosity, if you don't have a `where` clause in the trigger, what rows from `orders` turn up in `orders_archive`?

Comment: I do have a where clause. This is my original query in the ORDERS_IN_PROCESS table: 
`SELECT @soNo = soNo FROM INSERTED 
INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OrderID=@soNo`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that this has something to do with SSIS at all, but with your trigger. Instead of than `IN` that you have there, try using a `JOIN` in your query:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE 
SELECT O.* 
FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN INSERTED I
     ON O.ORderID = I.OrderID
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I've simplified my trigger to perform this operation
INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OrderID='9813' Shouldn't it add all the recs from ORDERS table with 9813 into ORDERS_ARCHVIE. It doesn't. I get only the last item in ORDERS_ARCHIVE from ORDERS.

Comment: @MarkK That is really weird. can you post the table definition of `ORDERS_ARCHIVE`?, you might have an unique index that is preventing duplicated records. What happens if you just run `INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OrderID='9813'` outside your trigger?

Comment: It's really a simple table with NO primary or foreign keys. It's an identical table as ORDERS with no triggers on it, either. Your query executed normally. I got 3 rows in ORDERS_ARCHIVE. This issue seems to be only from SSIS not in SSMS. Has to be some setting somewhere

Answer (score 3):

I concur with Lamark, misspelling intentional, with the assessment of your trigger is incorrect.

The logic you provided for your trigger does not compile. The WHERE clause is not valid. I'm assuming, as Lamak did that your intention was to join based on OrderID.

```
create table dbo.ORDERS_ARCHIVE
(
    OrderID int
,   ItemNo int
)
GO
create table dbo.ORDERS
(
    OrderID int
,   ItemNo int
)
GO
create trigger 
    trUpdate
ON
    dbo.ORDERS
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- This doesn't work
    -- Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trUpdate, Line 12
    -- The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.OrderID" could not be bound.
    --INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERS_ARCHIVE 
    --SELECT * 
    --FROM ORDERS 
    --WHERE OrderID=INSERTED.OrderID;

    -- I think you meant
    INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERS_ARCHIVE 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE OrderID=(SELECT INSERTED.OrderID FROM INSERTED);
 END
 GO
```

I then ginned up a simple SSIS package, I have a data source that supplies the 4 rows you indicated and writes to `dbo.ORDERS.` I ran the package 2 times and each one netted 4 rows in the ORDERS_ARCHIVE table. 3 rows with 9813, 1 with 9817 per batch.

I am getting the right count of rows in there so I believe the trigger is firing correctly. Instead, what is happening is the logic is incorrect. Since the OrderID is not unique in the ORDERS table, the database engine is going to pick the first row that happens to satisfy the search criteria. It just so happens that it picks the same row (ItemNo = 1) each time but since there is no guarantee of order without an `ORDER BY` clause, this is just random or an artifact of how the Engine chooses but no behaviour I would bank on remaining consistent.

### How do you fix this?

Fix the trigger. Joining to the inserted virtual table only on the OrderID is resulting in multiple rows satisfying the condition.

```
create trigger 
    trUpdate
ON
    dbo.ORDERS
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- This trigger will add all the rows from the ORDERS table
    -- that match what was just inserted based on OrderID and ItemNo
    INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERS_ARCHIVE 
    SELECT O.* 
    FROM dbo.ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN INSERTED I
         ON O.OrderID = I.OrderID
         AND O.ItemNo = I.ItemNo;
END
```

Now when I run the ETL, I see 4 rows in ORDERS_ARCHIVE with the correct `ItemNo` values.

Comment: WON'T WORK! The syntax "WHERE OrderID=INSERTED.OrderID" was used to minimize my typing. I know the right syntax. This is NOT the issue here. Your response in "How do you fix this" section is NOT what I'm looking for.  Please take a look at my original problem. What I need is when an order # gets written into ORDERS_IN_PROCESS, the trigger is on the ORDERS_IN_PROCESS table has to copy the ENTIRE order from ORDERS into ORDERS_ARCHIVE.

Comment: @MarkK: Provide the actual (trigger) code then, if you want others to help you fix it.

Comment: @ypercube: Here is the trigger code. I'm at a point where nothing is giving me my desired results so I hard coded the insert statment: `INSERT INTO ORDERS_ARCHIVE SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OrderID='9813'` It gives me just one row in ORDERS_ARHIVE. I need them ALL just like the query requests. I have no other triggers on any other tables. This only happens with inserts from SSIS NOT from SSMS.